# Why does Android Studio highlight some variables in white?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Some variables are highlighted in white since I use `Kotlin` code in Android Studio. Is this a warning?

[image: screenshot of Kotlin in Android Studio with these highlights]

Comment: It looks like you changed some default highlighting in the settings. Does it occur with the default settings as well?

Comment: That is the default setting. I only use `Monokai Sublime Text 3` for code style in Java and I did not change it for `Kotlin`

Comment: File | Manage IDE Settings | Restore Default Settings...: https://i.imgur.com/kbrkC7w.png.

Comment: I set the settings to default. There are still highlights but in a different color! https://s6.uupload.ir/files/untitled2_0fzw.png

Comment: What does the hint say if you hover over this element?

Comment: This is the hint: https://s6.uupload.ir/files/untitled3_hg31.png

Comment: Smart casts? https://i.imgur.com/MBrgbkl.png.

Comment: Thanks. I disabled the background for the Smartcast and there are no more highlights. So that was not a warning?

Comment: `contact` is a nullable type (let's call it ``Contact?``), so you have to check it's not null before you call a method on it, passing it to something that expects a non-null type, etc. That would get annoying, so one thing you can do is *cast* it to the non-null version, `val tempContact = contact as Contact` (no `?`). Now you have a variable that's a non-null type, no need to null-check it! What's happening here is Kotlin is *smart casting* `contact` to a non-null type automatically, because you checked it's not null, and it's not a `var` that could change to null partway through the block

Comment: The highlighting is just making you aware that's happening, and that your nullable variable is being handled safely. It happens in a few other places too - basically when it's smart enough to know something is "proven" to be a certain type, it will just let you treat it as that type without needing to add boilerplate code: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#smart-casts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDE highlights smart casts, you can disable it if you don't like it. It's not a warning.

[image: smart cast]